# Authorizing SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I wrote a method which will convert the word documents in a sharepoint library into PDF.

```
public WordToPDF(string fileName, string filePath, string userName, string passWord)

    {
        //Code to convert word to PDF.

    }
```

I can give the username and password hardcoded.But in runtime I am unable to use this method.Because you are unable to retrive the password in sharepoint.So How can I modify the above function? Thank YOU.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, I understood the question(:

If you are using this in a web part that will be published, 
you can elevate user priviliges.

Check [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB8QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fmicrosoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx&rct=j&q=elevate%20privileges%20sharepoint&ei=6at0TfnZCc_usgbEuZGEDg&usg=AFQjCNErpIXnv4rAz6jJ0LMW5-kxhp3eLg&cad=rja)

Comment: Hi Beytan, sorry for not clear. It is not the case of webpart.

Comment: If you are going to deploy it into sp, then this'll work. Whether it's in a webpart or else. 

Can you provide more detail please, then I can help.